How to exclude specific tabs in google sheet from script
Fairly inexperienced with google appscript
The code I am using is below and what I am trying to accomplish is to exclude specific tabs that the highlight change is not needed on.
function findDuplicatesAcrossSheets() {
  // Set the following variables to change the script's behavior
  const COLUMN_TO_CHECK = 13;  // A=1, B=2, etc.
  const HEADER_ROWS = 1;      // script will skip this number of rows

  dupeList = [];  // an array to fill with duplicates
  urlLocs = {};   // track which sheet(s) contain a url

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    numRows = sheets[i].getLastRow();
    if (numRows > HEADER_ROWS) {
      sheetName = sheets[i].getName();
      var data = sheets[i].getRange(HEADER_ROWS+1, COLUMN_TO_CHECK, numRows-HEADER_ROWS, 1).getValues();
      for (index in data) {
        row = parseInt(index) + HEADER_ROWS + 1;
        var url = data[index][0];
        if (url == "") {continue;}         // ignore empty url cells
        // We know we are looking at URLs, so we will do some cleanup specific to that type of data
        if (urlLocs.hasOwnProperty(url)) {
          dupeList.push("duplicate: " + url + " in sheet " + sheetName + " and sheet " + urlLocs[url].sheet);
          sheets[i].getRange(row,COLUMN_TO_CHECK,1,1).setBackground("pink");
          ss.getSheetByName(urlLocs[url].sheet).getRange(urlLocs[url].row,COLUMN_TO_CHECK,1,1).setBackground("pink");
        }
        urlLocs[url] = {sheet: sheetName, row: row};
      }
    }
  }
  if (dupeList.length > 0) {
    Browser.msgBox(dupeList.join("\\n"));
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox("No duplicates found")
  }
}

Have tried using var exclude and if(exclude.indexOf(ss.getSheets())) {continue;} but neither are working and break the script

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and Have tried using var exclude and if(exclude.indexOf(ss.getSheets())) {continue;} but neither are working and break the script. Also, I cannot understand your expected condition for skipping the specific sheets. Can I ask you about the details of them?

That bit at the end was just other code I had tried to use for the excluding. Essentially what the script does is go through every tab in the google sheet and collects data from a specific column and then highlights all the duplicates in pink . What I am trying to do is have it exclude just a couple tabs we don't want those highlighted duplicates on. Hope that explains it better.

Sorry if I've misunderstood, but if by tab to exclude, you mean skipping entire sheets, maybe an if after this line;
sheetName = sheets[i].getName();

Something like;
if(sheetName != "NAME OF SHEET" || sheetName != "NAME OF ANOTHER SHEET")

